# If $||\nabla f(x,y)||^2=2$, determine constants $a$ and $b$ such that $a(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u})^2-b(\frac{\partial g}{\partial v})^2=u^2+v^2.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The change of variables $x=uv$, $y=\frac{1}{2}\left(u^2-v^2\right)$ transforms $f(x,y)$ to $g(u,v).$

If $\left\|\nabla f(x,y)\right\|^2=2$ for all $x$ and $y$, determine constants $a$ and $b$ such that

$$a\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\right)^2-b\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right)^2=u^2+v^2.$$

Since $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}v+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}u$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}u-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}v$

$a\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\right)^2-b\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right)^2=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}^2 \left(av^2-bu^2\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}^2\left(au^2-bv^2\right)+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}uv(a+b)$

I cannot find a way to manipulate this to use the condition $\left\|\nabla f(x,y)\right\|^2=2$ and find the values for $a$ and $b$.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ \left\|\nabla f \right\| ^2 = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 = 2$.

Picking up on where you left, lets write down a system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 = 2 
\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}^2 \left(av^2-bu^2\right)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}^2\left(au^2-bv^2\right)+2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}uv(a+b) = u^2 + v^2
\end{cases}
$$

Collecting coefficients in front of the different powers of $u$ and $v$  in the second equation, and assuming non-trivial case $u\not\equiv0$ and $v\not\equiv0$, we write

$$
\begin{cases}
f_x^2 + f_y^2 = 2 
\\
f_x^2\left(av^2-bu^2\right)+
f_y^2\left(au^2-bv^2\right)+
2\,f_x \,f_y\, uv(a+b) = u^2 + v^2
\end{cases}
\iff
\\
\iff
\begin{cases}
f_x^2 + f_y^2 = 2 
\\
u^2\left(a \,f_y^2 - b\,f_x^2 - 1 \right) + v^2\left(a \,f_x^2 - b\,f_y^2 - 1 \right) + uv\left( \,f_x \, f_y \,\left( a+b\right)\right) = 0
\end{cases}
\implies
\\ 
\implies 
\begin{cases}
f_x^2 + f_y^2 = 2 \\
a \,f_y^2 - b\,f_x^2 = 1\\ 
a \,f_x^2 - b\,f_y^2 = 1 \\
 a+b = 0
\end{cases}
$$
In this way you have a system of for equations for the four unknowns, which are $a,b,f_x$, and $f_y$. Let us sum the second and the third equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
f_x^2 + f_y^2 = 2 \\
a \,f_y^2 - b\,f_x^2 = 1\\ 
a \,f_x^2 - b\,f_y^2 = 1 \\
 a+b = 0
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
f_x^2 + f_y^2 = 2 \\
a \left( f_x^2 + f_y^2\right) - b\left( f_x^2 + f_y^2\right) = 2\\  
 a+b = 0
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases} 
a - b = 1\\  
 a+b = 0
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases} 
a =  \frac{1}{2}\\  
b = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$